# What is the time needed to process information?

Tags: reaction-time

I read that the mind requires half a second to process visible info, so we see the world that existed half a second ago, right? I suppose this time has a certain range, due mainly to the age of the subject, do you have more precise data on such range according to various parameters?

Comment: Could you include the source where you read this, please? Questions on this site are expected to be based on referenced prior research. Including your source may fulfill that requirement.

Comment: sorry , it was long ago, please ignore my premise if it is out of place and sonsider a question about the range of time required to process info

Comment: Just copying from a [previous answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/25170/7001): "The inevitable corollary of neural binding is that our sense of the real-time present is mostly composed of events taking place in the recent past - sometimes referred to as the "specious present". How far in the past, or more specifically, the "temporal binding window" is highly variable, differs between individuals, and is affected by mental disorders, training, etc. It is also not so much a window as a probability distribution, but certainly extends to the hundreds of milliseconds."

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg, : 3-500 ,milliseconds, so, roughly a little less of half a second?

Comment: The time it takes to process information depends on its complexity and prior experience. In measures of reaction time you are simply looking at the time taken to register and respond to a stimulus, it's not really a general measure that can be applied beyond this. There are lots of studies on reaction time and its usually covered in basic psychology texts, even then the type of stimulus is an important variable.
Information processing really refers to a much more complex set of ideas.